# Convert a class string to TClass

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Given the Classes:
    uses
      InvokeRegistry; //where TRemotable is defined.
    type 
      TMyLabel = class(TRemotable)
      //some published props
      TMySubLabel = class(TMyLabel)
      //more published props

```
  //some other classes descendent of TMyLabel.

  TMyLabelClass = class of TMyLabel;
```

My requirement is to implement:

```
function StringToClass(string aClassName): TClass;
begin
  //your implementation goes here
end;
```

Usage:

```
function GetMyLabelInstance(string aClassName):TMyLabel; 
var
  lCloned: TMyLabel;
begin
  Tclass lClass = StringToClass('TMySubLabel');
  lCloned := TMyLabelClass(lClass).Create;
end;
```

I am using Delphi 7 and my objects are not derived from TPersistent, thus this solution is not applicable for my case:
[How to convert classname as string to a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727654/how-to-convert-classname-as-string-to-a-class)

Thanks,

Comment: [TOndrej's accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727654/how-to-convert-classname-as-string-to-a-class/2727962#2727962) to the question you linked doesn't make any assumptions about the class being a `TPersistent`, it works with whatever you add to the `TStringList`.

Comment: `Tclass lClass = StringToClass('TMySubLabel');` looks somewhat C-ish to me. Is that an acceptable syntax in (some variant of) Delphi or was that just a pseudo-code?

Comment: The answer is: function StringToClass(string aClassName): TClass; begin var lXSClass: TClass; begin lXSClass := RemClassRegistry.URIToClass('myUri', aClassName); Result := TMyLabelClass(lXSClass).Create; end; Thus question is not duplicate

Comment: No, it isn't. Your "answer" isn't actual code, and won't compile. And the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

As your classes are not `TPersistent` descendants, you have to implement your own `RegisterClass`/`FindClass` procedures.

I usually do this by registering the classes with their names in a `TStringList` (or `TDictionary<string, TClass>` for newer Delphi versions), as in [TOndrej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727654/how-to-convert-classname-as-string-to-a-class/2727962#2727962). I do the registration in the `initialization` section of the unit in which the class is defined.

Then you can have a `FindClass` function to retrieve the class based on his name, or directly a factory procedure which creates an instance, of the right class based on the name of the class.

I also consider a good practice to pack up the `TStringList`, the registration procedure and the factory procedure in one class implemented as a singleton.

If you want to use as a factory you also have to add a virtual constructor to the base class (TMyLabel), and define a metaclass type `TMyLabelClass = class of TMyLabel`, and cast the StringList.Objects[i] to TMyLabelClass instead of TClass

Comment: The answer is: function StringToClass(string aClassName): TClass; begin var lXSClass: TClass; begin lXSClass := RemClassRegistry.URIToClass('myUri', aClassName); Result := TMyLabelClass(lXSClass).Create; end; \r\nExplanation:
All my classes are descendent of TRemotable (defined at InvokeRegistry)
InvokeRegistry contains the RemClassRegistry.URIToClass method that reads the TClass value associated with it by RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass